# How to select a Button in list Button that have the same class

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a button in a for loop.

```
<button name="btnD" id="btnDetail" class="ddd" value="${comp.contentId}">Detail</button>
```

Those buttons will have the same `name` attribute in the HTML output. When I click one of them, I want to get the `value` attribute of it in jQuery.

Here is my script :

```
var btnDetail = $('button[name*="bd"]');
```

I know `btnDetail` is a list buttons that have `name` attribute containing `"bd"`, but I can't get the exact button which is just been clicked. How can I achive this?

Comment: Note that multiple elements with same ID is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) in HTML. I suggest to dynamically generate the ID as well, something like `id="btnDetail${loop.index}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "this" - it will refer to the current element

```
$('.ddd').click(function() {
     alert(this.value)
})
```

or:

```
$('button[name*="bd"]').click(function() {
     alert(this.value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("value"); can be used. $(this) is used to specify that element on which the event was triggered!
```